# Cisco AnyConnect VPN | Keys Not Recognized

Tags: vpn, cisco

I am connecting from home to work using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client, in a browser window. Everything works, but the key press events for [ and \ are not recognized. My keyboard works fine in every other application. It's a standard Querty desktop keyboard. All other key press events are relayed to the remote machine, but [ and \ do not produce any output.

Other symbols located on the same physical keys: { = shift+[ and |=shift+\ work fine.

My office PC seems to be running the "Citrix HDX Realtime Connector".
I am using Firefox.

How can I troubleshoot this? Which layer is capturing the [ and \ key press events? Where is this configurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine after making the following changes:

1. Use Chrome instead of Firefox
2. Mouse primary button is left (default setting, for a right-hand mouse)

Not sure which of these makes a difference. Will update once I've diagnosed it.

I keep my mouse on the left, and invert the buttons - both at home and at work.
But when I connect remotely, I need to set the button mapping on the work computer to be the default (primary: left). I still keep the buttons inverted on the local machine.